# Too many columns for one figure using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to split my matplotlib figure.
I am using this, and it is working, but the visualization is not good for having 260 bars side by side on the same plot. I have been trying to find a way to split the whole figure in two plots. The first 130 bars on one figure and the rest on another figure on the same page. So far I had no success. May I have some help, please?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
df1.iloc[:][1800].plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(df1.iloc[:]['gdp pc test'], rotation=85,     fontsize='small')
fig.set_size_inches(200, 30, forward=True)
```

Comment: Providing a minimal working example might help here. What is `df1`, which provides some sort of plotting function? Normally splitting the data shouldn't be too difficult, e.g. `df1.iloc[:130][1800].plot()`, `df1.iloc[130:][1800].plot()`?

Comment: df1 is the name of my data frame. I tried this approach, but it didn't work. 1800 is the name of my column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why my suggestion posted as a comment above won't work. For example (with a bit less data):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl

data = np.random.random((60,1))
df1  = pd.DataFrame(data)

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(211)
df1.iloc[:30][0].plot(kind='bar')
pl.subplot(212)
df1.iloc[30:][0].plot(kind='bar')
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bart. Probably because I was not using the subplot when writing each half. I will try the way you just showed me.

Comment: It worked Bart. Thank you very much. However, I am having some trouble to add the labels with your approach. Could you please give me a hint on how to add this in both subplots?                                    ax.set_xticklabels(df1.iloc[:]['gdp pc test'], rotation=85, fontsize='small')

Comment: Hey Bart, I figure that out. Thank you very much for all help and patience!